# Promises and nightmareJS in class Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, class, promise, nightmare

so I have this nightmare code that worked perfectly fine and I put it into a class. However it started throwing promise errors :-( (without the fun() function it works fine.

```js
class test {
  constructor() {
    this.init(() => {
      this.start()
    })
  }

  init() {
    this.nightmare = new Nightmare({
      show: true,
      typeInterval: 20,
      openDevTools: {
        detach: true
      }
    });
  }

  async start() {

    await this.nightmare
      .useragent(userAgent)
      .goto("https://www.yahoo.com")

    fun();

    async function fun() {
      await this.nightmare.goto('https://google.com')
    }
  }
}

new test().start();
```

The error is:

> (node:1101) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 1): TypeError: Cannot read property 'nightmare' of undefined
>
> (node:1101) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

Comment: Wrap your `await this.nightmare.goto('https://google.com')` in a `try catch`

Comment: have you tried `await fun();`? and what happens if you move the call after the function initialization?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with promises or await. You are getting an error because `this` does not refer to your object inside `fun()`. When you create a function and call it like you are with `fun()` you loose the `this` reference to your object. Consider:

```js
class test {
    constructor() {
        this.init()
    }
    
    init() {
        this.prop = "a property"
    }
    start() {
        console.log("this outside of fun: ", this)
        fun()
        function fun(){
            console.log("this in fun:", this)
        }
    }
}     
new test().start()
```

You will see that `this` is undefined in `fun()`.

Consider making `fun()` a real method and call it with `this.fun()` Alternatively you can manually bind `this` with something like:

```
 fun.call(this)
```